# Wix - How to install multiple windows services with one executable?

Tags: installation, wix

I'm trying to install multiple windows services with the same executable, but WiX doesn't like the same name attributes in the two file tags. I have tried changing the names of the two file tags. It works but I hope I don't have to install two of the same executable just for that purpose. Is there a better way to do this? Here's my code so far:

```
<Component Id="Service1" Guid="{SOMEGUID1}">
  <File Id='Service1' Name='ConnDriver.exe' DiskId='1' Source='..\Service\obj\x86\$(var.BUILD)\ConnDriver.exe'  KeyPath='yes'/>
    <ServiceInstall
      Id="ServiceInstaller1"
      Type="ownProcess"
      Name="MyService1"
      DisplayName="MyService1"
      Description="Some Description"
      Start="auto" 
      Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]"
      Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]"
      ErrorControl="normal"
      Arguments=' "Service1"'
      Vital="yes"
      Interactive="no" />
    <ServiceControl Id="ServiceControl1" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" Name="MyService1" Wait="yes" />
</Component>

<Component Id="Service2" Guid="{SOMEGUID2}">
  <File Id='Service2' Name='ConnDriver.exe' DiskId='1' Source='..\Service\obj\x86\$(var.BUILD)\ConnDriver.exe'  KeyPath='yes'/>
    <ServiceInstall
      Id="ServiceInstaller2"
      Type="ownProcess"
      Name="MyService2"
      DisplayName="MyService2"
      Description="Some Description"
      Start="auto" 
      Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]"
      Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]"
      ErrorControl="normal"
      Arguments=' "Service2"'
      Vital="yes"
      Interactive="no" />
    <ServiceControl Id="ServiceControl2" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" Name="MyService2" Wait="yes" />
</Component>
```

In features:

```
<Feature Id="Feature1" Title="Feature 2" Level="1" Description="...">
  <ComponentRef Id="Service1_xml"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="Service1"/>
</Feature>
<Feature Id="Feature2" Title="Feature 2" Level="1" Description="...">
  <ComponentRef Id="Service2_xml"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="Service2"/>
</Feature>
```

Any help is appreciated.

(PS. The reason I brake them up into 2 components is so that I can include an xml config file with the service in the features section. My windows service installer takes in a command line argument to know which xml file to read from and configure accordingly)

EDIT:

Error Output:

ICE30: The target file 'hlo8twix.exe|ConnDriver.exe' is installed in '[ProgramFilesFolder]\CompanyName\ProgramName\' by two different components on an LFN system: 'Service1' and 'Service2'. This breaks component reference counting.

Comment: Could you include the WiX output so that we have a better idea of how it's failing?

Comment: Looks like this can only be done through custom actions due to the nature of windows installer 
http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Using-the-same-exe-file-for-different-services-in-one-MSI-td6520212.html

Comment: I can confirm that this is possible using custom actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my projects, I have 2 services inside of one executable. So for both services in my exe, I have the following in my wix setup.  Hope this helps.

```
  <Component Id="MyScheduler" Guid="{SOMEGUID}">
    <File Id="MySchedulerEXE" Name="MyScheduler.exe" Source="MyScheduler.exe" KeyPath="yes" />

    <ServiceInstall Id="FirstService" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Name="First Service" DisplayName="First Service" Description="First Service" Start="auto" Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" Interactive="no" ErrorControl="ignore" />
    <ServiceControl Id="StartFirstService" Name="First Service" Start="install" Wait="no" />
    <ServiceControl Id="StopFirstService" Name="First Service" Stop="both" Wait="yes" Remove="uninstall" />

    <ServiceInstall Id="SecondService" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Name="Second Service" DisplayName="Second Service" Description="Second Service" Start="auto" Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" Interactive="no" ErrorControl="ignore" />
    <ServiceControl Id="StartSecondService" Name="Second Service" Start="install" Wait="no" />
    <ServiceControl Id="StopSecondService" Name="Second Service" Stop="both" Wait="yes" Remove="uninstall" />

  </Component>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did and it worked. In my case there was a twist though: you could select how many service instances you wanted installed. To do this, I had to duplicate the whole component with an exclusive condition; one component with one install/control pair, another with two pair, another with three etc.

Comment: I've tried this, and can't get it to work. The first service in the array of `ServiceBase` that gets passed into `ServiceBase.Run()` does run, but not the ones that come after that. Any ideas?

Comment: I have go same issue as Farinha. If i install it with "InstallUtil.exe" then both services run fine. but with wix installer it only runs the first one. infact it does not care about the name, it just runs the first service. somebody please find the problem

Comment: Finally found the solution. for multple services in same exe, you have to set Type="shareProcess" in ServiceInstall element and both the services will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A component can belong to more than one feature. Create a single component for your service, then multiple features: each feature has a `ComponentRef` to the one service component and whatever other references it needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think the hard part then, is to find a way to get the command line argument in that one component to change with each feature.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. for multple services in same exe, you have to set Type="shareProcess" in ServiceInstall element and both the services will work just fine.
I found this out by installing my service using "InstallUtil" and compared the registry structure. "InstallUtil" set type to ownProcess, so i changed mine in installer too and that worked like a charm.

```
<Component Id="MyScheduler" Guid="{SOMEGUID}">
<File Id="MySchedulerEXE" Name="MyScheduler.exe" Source="MyScheduler.exe" KeyPath="yes" />

    <ServiceInstall Id="FirstService" Type="shareProcess" Vital="yes" Name="First Service" DisplayName="First Service" Description="First Service" Start="auto" Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" Interactive="no" ErrorControl="ignore" />
    <ServiceControl Id="StartFirstService" Name="First Service" Start="install" Wait="no" />
    <ServiceControl Id="StopFirstService" Name="First Service" Stop="both" Wait="yes" Remove="uninstall" />

    <ServiceInstall Id="SecondService" Type="shareProcess" Vital="yes" Name="Second Service" DisplayName="Second Service" Description="Second Service" Start="auto" Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" Interactive="no" ErrorControl="ignore" />
    <ServiceControl Id="StartSecondService" Name="Second Service" Start="install" Wait="no" />
    <ServiceControl Id="StopSecondService" Name="Second Service" Stop="both" Wait="yes" Remove="uninstall" />

  </Component>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- The name of the product -->
<?define Service1Name = "Test Service1" ?>
<?define Service2Name = "Test Service2" ?>
<!-- The description of the product -->
<?define Service1Description = "Test Service1 that logs dummy text on an interval to a text file." ?>
<?define Service2Description = "Test Service2 that logs dummy text on an interval to a text file." ?>
<!-- The manufacturer, for setup package publisher and folder info -->
<?define Manufacturer = "Your Company" ?>
<!-- The version number of this setup package-->
<?define Version = "1.0.1" ?>
<!-- UpgradeCode must be unique and not changed once the first version of the program is installed. -->
<?define UpgradeCode = "{1240E0CD-B3D2-44A7-B064-11B3C0709D69}" ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.Service1Name)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" Version="$(var.Version)" Language="1033">
    <!-- Create a folder inside Your Company called Test Service -->
    <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes"/>
    <!-- Create a folder inside Your Company called Test Service -->
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="TestService.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <!-- Allow upgrades and prevent downgrades -->
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." />
    <!-- Define the directory structure -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <!-- Create a folder inside program files called Your Company -->
        <Directory Id="ROOTDIRECTORY" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <!-- Create a folder inside Your Company called Test Service -->
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.Service1Name)" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <!-- The files inside this DirectoryRef are linked to the Test Service directory via INSTALLFOLDER -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <!-- Create a single component which is the TestService.exe file -->
      <Component Id="$(var.TestService1.TargetFileName)">
        <!-- Copies the TestService.exe file using the project reference preprocessor variables -->
        <File Id="$(var.TestService1.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.TestService1.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
        <!-- Remove all files from the INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
        <RemoveFile Id="RemoveService1" Name="*.*" On="both" />
        <!-- Tell WiX to install the Service -->
        <ServiceInstall Id="Service1Installer"
        Type="ownProcess"
        Name="TestService1"
        DisplayName="$(var.Service1Name)"
        Description="$(var.Service1Description)"
        Start="auto"
        ErrorControl="normal" />
        <!-- Tell WiX to start the Service -->
        <ServiceControl Id="StartService1" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="TestService1" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
      <!-- Create a single component which is the TestService.exe file -->
      <Component Id="$(var.TestService2.TargetFileName)">
        <!-- Copies the TestService.exe file using the project reference preprocessor variables -->
        <File Id="$(var.TestService2.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.TestService2.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
        <!-- Remove all files from the INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
        <RemoveFile Id="RemoveService2" Name="*.*" On="both" />
        <!-- Tell WiX to install the Service -->
        <ServiceInstall Id="Service2Installer"
        Type="ownProcess"
        Name="TestService2"
        DisplayName="$(var.Service2Name)"
        Description="$(var.Service2Description)"
        Start="auto"
        ErrorControl="normal" />
        <!-- Tell WiX to start the Service -->
        <ServiceControl Id="StartService2" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="TestService2" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <!-- Tell WiX to install the files -->
    <Feature Id="Feature1" Title="TestService1.Setup" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="$(var.TestService1.TargetFileName)" />
    </Feature>
    <Feature Id="Feature2" Title="TestService2.Setup" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="$(var.TestService2.TargetFileName)" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```