# Installing Multiple .Net services with Wix 3.7 only the first one runs

Tags: .net, service, wix

I am installing multiple .net windows services.  All the services install all the dependencies in the appropriate folders.  However, only the first one will run.  The other services give Error 1053: The service did not start to the respond or control request in a timely fashion.

Thoughts?

Edit: This doesn't take 30 seconds.  It happens in about 1 second.

Edit:

```
 <ComponentGroup Id="IngestServiceComponents" Directory="IngestINSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="IngestService" Guid="5a95ee28-c9da-46b9-8396-cef98fa8fcbb">
    <File Id="IssueIngestService.exe" Name="IngestService.exe" Source="..\IngestService\bin\Release\IngestService.exe" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/>
    <File Id="IngestService.exe.config" Name="IngestService.exe.config" Source="..\IngestService\bin\Release\IngestService.exe.config" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
    <File Id="Libraries2_1" Name="Libraries2.dll" Source="..\IngestService\bin\Release\Libraries2.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
    <File Id="DLibraries2_1" Name="DLibraries2.dll" Source="..\IngestService\bin\Release\DLibraries2.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
    <File Id="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib_1" Name="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll" Source="..\..\Assemblies\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
    <File Id="ChilkatDotNet45_1" Name="ChilkatDotNet45.dll" Source="..\..\Assemblies\ChilkatDotNet45.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
    <File Id="MediaInfo_1" Name="MediaInfo.dll" Source="..\..\Assemblies\MediaInfo.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
    <File Id="XmpToolkit_1" Name="XmpToolkit.dll" Source="..\..\Assemblies\XmpToolkit.dll" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
    <File Id="ffmpeg.exe_1" Name="ffmpeg.exe" Source="..\..\Assemblies\ffmpeg.exe" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1"/>
    <ServiceInstall
                Id="IngestServiceInstaller"
                Type="ownProcess"
                Vital="yes"
                Name="IngestService"
                DisplayName="Ingest"
                Description="Ingest Service"
                Start="auto"
      Account="user"
      Password="password"
                ErrorControl="ignore"
                Interactive="no">
    </ServiceInstall>
    <ServiceControl Id="IngestStartService" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="IngestService" Wait="no" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Comment: Not a lot to go on here. Can you share the .wxs code you are using to do the install? Also, did you verify the services can start when the error dialog is up? Basically, need more information.

Comment: Added Wix snippet.  I have 4 of the same blocks.  The first one in the sequence works.  The following 3 don't start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was user error as usual.  The first service was .net Framework 4.0.  All the new ones were 4.5.  Framework 4.5 wasn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

Given the example above, I would have to guess that something is going awry in your installation services. You have `ServiceControl/@Wait='no'` so that means the 4 services could be started almost all at the same time. Is it possible that they are colliding with each other and only one survives the start up?

You might consider using `ServiceControl/@Wait='yes'` and otherwise debugging the services. When the error dialog comes up, you should be able to see and start the services (either through `services.msc` or `sc.exe` from the command-line). Leave the error dialog up and debug to see what might be going wrong.

There isn't anything obviously wrong with your setup code.

PS: putting that many files, particularly other executables, in a single `Component` is not a best practice. See the [Component Rules](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2003/10/18/component-rules-101) for why.

Comment: So, using the current wxs code all the services install correctly.  I also do not auto start the services.  If collision were the issue I would be able to start them from services.msc.  The only one that starts is the first one.  Don't know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer here. i was struggling with same problem for hours
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35510262/2903863